# AngularJS how to set dynamically value of binding element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I need, based on an *in page variable*, to change value of a binding element.

Here it is the in page var:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myVar = 'value1';
</script>
```

---

This is the select with the bind element:

---

```
<select value="">
 <option ng-repeat="value in valueList">
  {{myNewValue()}}
 </option>
</select>
```

---

Here is the controller:

---

```
$scope.inPageVar = $window.myVar;

$http.get(jsonUrl).then(function(result) {
    $scope.valueList = result.data.valueList;
    $scope.myNewValue = function() {
      return $scope.valueList[0].additional + $scope.inPageVar;
    };
});
```

---

Here the JSON structure:

---

```
"valueList": [
          {
            "additionnal": {
              "value1": "this is value 1",
              "value2": "this is value 2"
            }
          },
          {
            "additionnal": {
              "value1": "this is value 3",
              "value2": "this is value 4"
            }
          }
        ]
```

I would like to know how to concatenate the in-page var value with the element of the get function.. Thank you!

Comment: You can't achieve this until you make the myVar as global or add it to $rootScope

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to assign a javascript variable in angular controller ?

Comment: I want to have the result as this: $scope.myNewValue + $scope.inPageVar
like if I have 'result.data.valueList.additional. <- the last one is the in page var

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {

  angular.module("CombineModule", []).controller('MyController', function() {
    this.values = [{
      "additional": {
        "value1": "this is value 1",
        "value2": "this is value 2"
      }
    }, {
      "additional": {
        "value1": "this is value 3",
        "value2": "this is value 4"
      }
    }];

    this.myNewValue = function(index) {
      return this.values[index].additional[myVar];
    };
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="CombineModule">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
    var myVar = 'value1';
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController as v">
  <select value="">
    <option ng-repeat="value in v.values">
      {{v.myNewValue($index)}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to expose myVar globally,

write `window.myVar = 'some value'` instead of `var myVar = 'someval'`.

Or if you want to make this available into `$rootScope.myVar = 'some value'`

Then in your logic,

`return $scope.valueList[0].additional[window.myVar];`

Comment: the myVar comes from the backend and it is printed inside the HTML in a <script></script>

I want to expose it globally to use it like this: 'result.data.valueList.additional. <- the last one is the in page var myVar

Comment: uhm but if I write console.log($scope.inPageVar); it prints the myVar value

Comment: So do you mean you're able to get the value of variable but not assign it ?

Comment: @paolopolix Updated the answer with snippet